# how to remove the property name from json generated by sql?

Tags: sql, json

Here is the sql query :

```
select a.MATRICULE as id , 
       a.MATRIC_SUPERIEUR as pid , 
       g.NOM + ' ' +g.prenom as name , 
       t.INTITULE as title 
from  CLASSIFICATION c, AFFECTATION a,AGENT g ,TABLE_REFERENCE t
where a.MATRICULE = g.MATRICULE 
and CODE=c.FONCTION 
and c.MATRICULE = g.MATRICULE 
for json auto
```

the generated json :

```
{"id":"1111","pid":"","name":"Hilmi Mehdi","t":[{"title":"Fonction 1"}]}
```

How to make it like this

```
{"id":"1111","pid":"","name":"Hilmi Mehdi","title":"Fonction 1"}
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Why is this tagged with `javascript`? What db system is this? What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: i'am using javascript to parse the json then use the data to create an organizationa chart . sql server

Comment: _"i'am using javascript to parse the json then use the data to create an organizationa chart"_ - Which is not relevant for the problem/question. Please fix the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

It shows a few different ways of going about this (option 1 probably suiting your use case the best).